# Converting SQL script to LINQ with IN clause

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying to work out how to covert the script below from SQL in to LINQ. Any help would be welcome.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    [tableName]
WHERE
[MyDate] IN
    (SELECT
        MAX([MyDate])
   FROM
      [tableName]
   GROUP BY
      [MyID])
```

I can't find an equivalent for the "IN" clause section. There are existing questions on this forum but none that cover selecting a DateTime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Any()` is what you are looking for:

```
var result = tableName.Where(x => 
                (from t in tableName
                group t by t.MyID into g
                where g.Max(y => y.MyDate) == x.MyDate
                select 1).Any())
```

Comment: Surely Any() just returns true or false, depending on whether results exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ".Contains(..)" function:
e.g.

```
var itemQuery = from cartItems in db.SalesOrderDetails
              where cartItems.SalesOrderID == 75144
              select cartItems.ProductID;

var myProducts = from p in db.Products
                where itemQuery.Contains(p.ProductID)
                select p;
```

Although it looks like 2 round trips, as the LINQ only constructs the query when the IEnumerable is tripped, you should get reasonable performance.

Comment: I am trying to return all the max dates from the query so I'm not **contains(...)** can be used in this case.

Comment: If your first query got the max dates e.g. var maxDates = from ... then your second query could use WHERE maxDates.Contains(myDate)

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to do the grouping/max in LINQ, as you didn't ask this in your question

Comment: I did wonder that but thought there must be a better way like in my original SQL example.

Comment: The LINQ engine would probably compile it to a single query like your SQL one.